# REST Yii2 - how to display non-UTF8 characters coming from database in json?

Tags: json, rest, utf-8, yii2, firebird

I am building Yii2 REST application that uses WIN1257 (not UTF8) encoded Firebird 2.1 database. I can get json result if data does not containt non-latin letters but when varchar fields contain non-latin language specifice characters then I get errors message:

```
malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded., "yii\base\InvalidParamException"
```

Full stack trace is:

```
{
  "name": "Exception",
  "message": "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded.",
  "code": 5,
  "type": "yii\\base\\InvalidParamException",
  "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\helpers\\BaseJson.php",
  "line": 123,
  "stack-trace": [
    "#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\helpers\\BaseJson.php(61): yii\\helpers\\BaseJson::handleJsonError(5)",
    "#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\web\\JsonResponseFormatter.php(89): yii\\helpers\\BaseJson::encode(Array, 320)",
    "#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\web\\JsonResponseFormatter.php(73): yii\\web\\JsonResponseFormatter->formatJson(Object(yii\\web\\Response))",
    "#3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\web\\Response.php(948): yii\\web\\JsonResponseFormatter->format(Object(yii\\web\\Response))",
    "#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\web\\Response.php(312): yii\\web\\Response->prepare()",
    "#5 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\base\\Application.php(381): yii\\web\\Response->send()",
    "#6 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myproject\\web\\index.php(12): yii\\base\\Application->run()",
    "#7 {main}"
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to derive some class that converts those characters into UTF8 characters before presenting them to json formatter? The database migration to UTF8 is currently out of reach, web application should adapt to the requirements in this case.

Comment: If your database has an explicit character set for all (relevant) columns, then you can use the connection character set to convert for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just convert your string from WIN1257 to UTF-8? Try libiconv:

```
$str = iconv("CP1257", "UTF-8", $str);
```

Sadly, at the time of writing, `mb_convert_encoding` [does not support](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php) CP1257.

I believe the best solution overall would be to create a getter/setter pair for the attribute. Assume your original table column name is `example_field`. Add the following methods to your model:

```
public function getExampleField()
{
    return iconv("CP1257", "UTF-8", $this->example_field);
}

public function setExampleField($value)
{
    $this->example_field = iconv("UTF-8", "CP1257", $value);
}
```

That way you can transparently use `$model->exampleField` as an attribute. Your application does not even need to know of the encoding behind the scenes.

Comment: iconv is working and mb_convert_encoding does not support CP1257. These function must be called from afterFind and beforeSave methods, e.g. http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/49296-using-csecuritymanager-to-encryptdecrypt-data/ And then the problem is solved.

Comment: I guess you're right, mb_convert_encoding does not support CP1257. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Using `beforeSave` is a bad idea - consider what would happen if you tried to save your model more than once. Use a getter/setter pair.

Comment: At present I don't why, but the use of getter methods does not remove error, use of afterFind removes error.